# Is possible to denote a vector of numbers uniquely as a number?

Tags: algorithm, vector, compression, distributed, canonical-link

Given a vector of numbers: V=(v1, v2, ..., vn). These n numbers don't need to be distinct or sorted.

Suppose that we have a few vectors V1, V2, ..., Vm. Is possible to use a number (integer or float number) to uniquely denote each vector, such that for any Vi not equal Vj, the corresponding numbers f(Vi) and f（Vj) are not equal either.

A simple solution is to have one number in the range from 0 to m-1 as an ID to represent a vector, however we assume that this kind of solution cannot work in the case that each vector is stored in a few distributed machines. That is, the portions of vectors in two machines might overlap, and the algorithm doesn't know the distribution of vectors globally.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff It's only a hash if the output is fixed-size, and then you inevitable face the danger of collisions (by the pigeonhole principle).

Comment: @delnan - You must have about 2^32 pigeons to get a real chance of 64-bit hash collision.  :-)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff There are plenty of applications where the odds of a collision are negligible as the hash function is near-perfect. But one needs to be sure it's actually like that (a bad hash function and/or patterns in the input data can make collisions very realistic -- as a simple example, consider a `mod x` function applied to multiples of `x`), and one needs to **think** whether the possibility of collisions, however remote, matters.

Comment: @delnan - Of course, hash function must be good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the inputs are in principle unbounded and so is the output number, as it's trivial otherwise. A simple way is just concatenations the representations of n and v1, v2, .. vn in some base b. Represent them in k-bit digits, then annotate each k-bit digit with a continuation bit (0 if the next k-bit group starts a new number, 1 if it belongs to the same number). This isn't of much use for anything except equality tests, but you did not mention anything else.

If you also care about preserving locality (i.e. nearby points p, q frequently have nearby values f(p), f(q)), some space-filling curves can be used for this purpose. The [Hilbert curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve) is a bit complicated to generalize to higher dimensions, and the calculation is nontrivial. The [Z-order curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_%28curve%29) isn't as good at preserving locality, but it's almost trivial to implement for any number of dimensions -- just interleave the bits of the binary representation.

Comment: OP wants `to use a number (integer or float number) to uniquely denote each vector`.  Output number is NOT unbounded, 8 bytes is a maximum.  Hash is the key to choose.  ;-)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff There's arbitrary-precision integers, and floating point numbers can use variable precision as well (e.g. see the `decimal` types in many standard libraries). In this context, unless OP states that the output must be k bits, I'm going to assume there is no such limit.

Comment: Are using of arbitrary-precision numbers something better than using simple comma-separated string of those numbers?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Sure. For starters, it's approximately eight times more compact and it's conceptually simpler to generate and consume. Plus, a variable-length ASCII string (ignoring unicode strings) is, from a certain point of view, just an arbitrary precision number in base 127 with some pointless 0 bits, so what exactly do you hope to gain from it?

Answer (score 1):

Of course if you have n numbers you can't compress them to one number of the same length without losing information (e.g. if you calculate some kind of hash from the vector, there will be hash collisions).

If you have unlimited space (like a BigInteger in Java), you can encode the vectors. Assuming that the vector length is fixed, you can simply use some "interlocking" pattern:

```
vector = [12345,4711,42]

1  2  3  4  5
 0  4  7  1  1
  0  0  0  4  2
100240370414512 <-- your unique number
```

It shouldn't be too hard to encode the vector size as well, so this would work for vectors of different sizes as well (e.g. you use the length in octal and an 8 as "prefix").

Comment: Thanks for your answering! These are awesome solutions, however, hash might cause collisions and "interlocking pattern" could cost more space.